# Internet explorer and google chrome frame can support webRTC?

Tags: sip, voip, webrtc

I have tried and tested various approaches to make webRTC work on internet explorer

1. using Google chrome plugin
2. webRTC4all

Sipml5 is not responding to either of these approaches

I also read the "Customizable, Ubiquitous Real Time Communication over the Web (CU-RTC-Web)
Real-Time Media and Peer-to-Peer Transport API " document which is still in development stage and not version is released .

Could someone tell me a solution to the problem , or correct me if i am wrong .

Comment: webRTC is still in Working Draft, i.e. is not yet supported among browsers yet. However, Chrome, Opera and Firefox Nightly 18 (require to enable in `about:config`) are supported; IE is not in the list. You probably can't make it happen in IE at this moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay i am going to answer my own question here .. after months of wait , IE has decided to make Sype like WebRTC ( plugin free ) http://venturebeat.com/2014/10/27/microsoft-eyes-webrtc-for-plugin-free-skype-calls-in-internet-explorer/. however no details / confirmation available up-till now

Answer (score 2):

WebRTC is supported now in Chrome Stable and Firefox Beta, and in Internet Explorer via Chrome Frame: see my [blog post](http://samdutton.wordpress.com/2012/08/09/how-to-use-webrtc-in-internet-explorer-with-chrome-frame/), which has a screencast video showing this in action. Support in Opera mobile and desktop is planned.