# Media Server for WebRTC

Tags: html, internet-explorer, webrtc

We are trying to develop a web conferencing application using WebRTC. It's lack of support for IE browsers is really big pain point for us. Now we are trying to deploying a media server that can possibly do a http live streaming for non WebRTC browsers. We tried with Kurento Media Server, but unfortunately it doesn't go well with cloud. I'm clue less on how to proceed now. Can anyone help me with this regards.

P.s. Consider me as a rookie in WebRTC.

Comment: Well you could use a fallback mechanism that is supported in IE (like Flash)

Comment: @ziaud Which problems did you have with cloud? We have some servers running in the Amazon Cloud and they are working fine.

Comment: @Izan: are you asking about kurento?

Comment: @ziaud Yeah, I'm asking about Kurento. We have successfully set-up Kurento in AWS several times. What is your current setup and which problems did you find?

Answer (score 1):

[Priologic (easyRTC) just released an open source WebRTC plugin](http://bloggeek.me/webrtc-plugin-free-open-source/) for IE.

HTTP Live Streaming has several seconds of delay. Not suitable for the real-time communication.

Comment: Thanks much bro, nice piece of info.

Answer (score 1):

There are several alternative/complements that you can use in order to make videos work in IE.

First of all, please ask yourself if this is really needed. Are the people that will use your solution using IE ? If yes, could yo convince them to use <s>a more decent</s> another browser ?

If you really can't do that, then :

- You could ask your users to install a plugin, like https://code.google.com/p/webrtc4all/
- You could also use a fallback mechanism, like flash. Unfortunately, I don't know of any simple way to do that right now. You will probably have to build your solution from scratch. And the quality will probably suffer. *EDIT* : found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349407/webrtc-shim-for-browsers-that-dont-support-webrtc?rq=1), with a commercial Java applet.
- Also see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706615/internet-explorer-and-google-chrome-frame-can-support-webrtc) related to chrome frame and a [google groups conversation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/discuss-webrtc/tKoh1wrI8ig/MPTdCHpgcm4J)

But really, I would just forget IE if I were you...